# keep column width using responsive table bootstrap3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a table with 7 columns (td). I'm setting a fixed width and it's working perfectly using a browser on desktop. However, When I resize my browser to simulate a mobile phone or even accessing this page through a mobile device, it won't respect column width.

I won't put the entire html, but it's basically:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table>
         <tr>
              <td class="w-large">Column 1</td>
              <td class="w-medium">Column 2</td>
              <td class="w-medium">Column 3</td>
              <td class="w-medium">Column 4</td>
              <td class="w-medium">Column 5</td>
              <td class="w-medium">Column 6</td>
              <td class="w-medium">Column 7</td>
         </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.w-large {
    width: 198px;
}

.w-medium {
    width: 176px;
}
```

Is there a way to keep column width on mobile? Does bootstrap have a special class to do this similar to table-responsive?

Comment: Do you really need a table-responsive if you have fixed columns ??

Comment: Why would you use a table when you're using a grid system?

Comment: Why does the table-responsive class is not on your table but on your parent div ?

Comment: Well, I've tried a grid system before, and my client didn't like it. So I switched to table responsive, which include a scroll. For our need, it's better. But I would like to keep column width since I have a scroll.

Comment: @TheLittlePig -- the .table-responsive is supposed to wrap the table, not be on the table itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

.table-responsive is supposed to be as you have it, on the wrapper around the table. The widths won't be kept because the class puts a  `white-space: nowrap;` on th, td, etc. Do this instead:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .alt-table-responsive {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: auto;
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="alt-table-responsive">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Christina!